# Is it possible to sense the depth of a well?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I use BC Quarries quite often, but I want to be able to monitor their progress through a computer. Is it possible to sense the depth of a well (or the quarry, or the water) using an item? Modpack is Tech World 2.

Comment: I don't think there is a single item, but there should be the option to set up a turtle+other computercraft stuff to somehow count that for you

Answer (score 2):

Option 1) You could use a turtle as the quarry, there are many programs already available which link to computers and the screens in CC(even terminal glasses) Turtles are pretty good quarries and when you add chunkloader to them and rednet they are incredible

[This is my Favourite](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/5681-variable-size-quarry/)

Option 2) Write your own program for a turtle which connects to a terminal through rednet, have the turtle dig along side the quarry and tell it to stop if there is still a block next to it. then program it to send its Y coordinate to the computer.

You can use code that has already been written in other programs and put your code together that way.